# How do I use the accuracy of the previous iteration of training a neural network as the baseline for Early Stopping in the following iteration?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Like the question states, I want the baseline in my early stopping callback to equal that of the previous iteration. Is there a way I can update that early stopping parameter as the neural network continues to be trained.

Here is some code-

```
es_acc = EarlyStopping(monitor='acc', baseline=0, verbose=0, patience=0)

gs = BayesSearchCV(model, param_grid, cv=2, n_iter=5, n_jobs=1,
                   optimizer_kwargs={'base_estimator': 'RF'},
                   fit_params={"callbacks": [es_acc, tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots()]})
```

So for each iteration I want to update the `baseline` parameter in `es_acc`. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the `EarlyStopping` class in callbacks.py, change `on_epoch_end` to the following:

```
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    current = self.get_monitor_value(logs)
    if current is None:
      return
    if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.best):
      self.best = current
      if current > self.baseline:
        self.baseline = current
      self.wait = 0
      if self.restore_best_weights:
        self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
    else:
      self.wait += 1
      if self.wait >= self.patience:
        self.stopped_epoch = epoch
        self.model.stop_training = True
        if self.restore_best_weights:
          if self.verbose > 0:
            print('Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.')
          self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)
```

But make sure that you redefine your `EarlyStopping` callback variable for every iteration (if using a for loop).